# Transaction inside the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

```
USE [incentive]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_empincentivefinal] 
    (@id int,                    
     @ConsultantName varchar(50) ,                  
     @ClientName varchar(50) ,      
     @StartDate varchar(50),     
     @PositionName varchar(20) ,  
     @Location varchar(20) ,       
     @Job_Status varchar (20),  
     @RecruiterName varchar(20),                    
     @BenchMarketing varchar(1) ,                  
     @Placement varchar(1),  
     @CompanyName varchar(20),        
     @Durations varchar(20),             
     @DurationofProject varchar(10) 
     --@out int out    
    )           
AS                
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO [tbl_Empincentivenew1](ConsultantName, ClientName, RecruiterName, PositionName, CompanyName, Location, DurationofProject, Durations, BenchMarketing, Placement, Job_Status, StartDate)                  
        OUTPUT INSERTED.id 
        DEFAULT VALUES

        COMMIT
    END          
GO
```

My table is not inserted with id when I am running the procedure, but when I am executing the transaction part alone, the id value gets inserted.

Could you please help?

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: no ..no errors are there,command executed succesfully but the id is not inserted when running the sp along with the transaction

Comment: *Side note*: please always use the **most appropriate** datatype - and defining an obvious `@StartDate` **date** value as `varchar(50), ` is **NOT** the most appropriate way to do it! If it looks like a date, smells like a date, quacks like a date - then **IT IS** a date and then you should also use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` as your datatype - **not** varchar!

Comment: yes..@marc_s i change the data type but still it is doing the same

Answer (score 0):

If you add TRAN after the commit command like this:

> COMMIT TRAN

Does that help ?

Comment: No @Alex...again the same result.. :(